# Jackson MixIn to replace the generic class JAXBElement<T> with its T behind getValue()

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, jackson

I'm trying to bind XML and JSON using the same JAXB annotations (using the [JaxbAnnotationModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations)).

```
XML <--> JAXB <--> Jackson <--> JSON
```

I have to use the JAXB annotation and cannot alter them. My problem is that some XMLs convert to the generic class `JAXBElement<T>` instead of a class `T` directly. That leads to the JSON output:

```
{  
   "JAXBElement":{  
      "name":"{http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0}Capabilities",
      "declaredType":"net.opengis.wps.v_1_0_0.WPSCapabilitiesType",
      "scope":"javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope",
      "value":{  
         "ProcessOfferings":{  },
         "Languages":{  },
         "ServiceIdentification":{  },
         "ServiceProvider":{  },
         "OperationsMetadata":{  },
         "version":"1.0.0",
         "updateSequence":"1",
         "service":"WPS",
         "lang":"en-US"
      },
      "nil":false,
      "globalScope":true,
      "typeSubstituted":false
   }
}
```

While I instead want:

```
{  
   "Capabilities":{  
     "ProcessOfferings":{  },
     "Languages":{  },
     "ServiceIdentification":{  },
     "ServiceProvider":{  },
     "OperationsMetadata":{  },
     "version":"1.0.0",
     "updateSequence":"1",
     "service":"WPS",
     "lang":"en-US"
   }
}
```

The real object of type `T` is wrapped by an JAXBElement. This may happen for some root elements and nested anywhere in the object tree as well. If I call `getValue()` on that I'll get the real object. But I can't do this when the `JAXBElement<T>` is not the root element since Jackson is the only interpreter between JAXB and JSON and I can neither alter the JAXB-Binding nor the created objects (some other parts of the code use them, too).

So what I found what might solve the problem are [MixIns](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations):

```
// a mixin annotation that overrides the handling for the JAXBElement
public static interface JAXBElementMixin<T> {
    @JsonValue
    Object getValue();
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
mapper.registerModule(module);
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(JAXBElement.class, JAXBElementMixin.class);
```

That solves the problem of the additional elements but causes the name of the object to be `JAXBElement` instead of `T` (in my case `Capabilities`):

```
{  
  "JAXBElement":{  // <------ Should be 'Capabilities' because of type JAXBElement<Capabilities>
    "ProcessOfferings":{  },
    "Languages":{  },
    "ServiceIdentification":{  },
    "ServiceProvider":{  },
    "OperationsMetadata":{  },
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "updateSequence":"1",
    "service":"WPS",
    "lang":"en-US"
  }
}
```

**The questions:**

Any idea what I can do (maybe annotate `JAXBElementMixin<T>`) to get the correct type `Capabilities` as object name (there are other classes instead of `Capabilities` that can be placed as `T`, too)?

Any other idea how to skip the serialization of any `JAXBElement<T>` anywhere in the object tree and continue with the serialization of the object behind its `getValue()` method?

Comment: As you're working with WPS you might be interested in the [ogc-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) project.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer to your question, but possibly a recipe to achieve your goal.

If you just want to get rid of the topmost `JAXBElement`, why don't you just customize XJC to generate an additional class for your `Capabilities` element?

Something like:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='Capabilities']">
   <jaxb:class name="Capabilities"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This should generate a class `Capabilities` annotated with '@XmlRootElement'. Thus you'll get rid of the `JAXBElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does not support `JAXBElement`, as it is very much XML-specific and is difficult to make work with other formats: Jackson JAXB support is focused on using information from annotations to make things work, but goal is not to be a full JAXB implementation.

As such your best bet is to do what @lexicore suggests and try to avoid use of `JAXBElement`.